# What's the purpose of the both bars in character creation?

Tags: soul-calibur-3

It changes whenever I choose different cosmetics. Does this make an impact in gameplay or otherwise?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a thread on gamefaqs found at https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps2/927089-soulcalibur-iii/answers/101280-what-are-the-two-bars-on-charactor-creation:

> TOP ONE: (GOOD AND EVIL) If the dot on the bar is towards left, the
>   character is good, if the dot towards right, the character is evil.
>   You can change the dot's location depending on the clothing. (Has no
>   effect on character performance)
>
> BOTTOM ONE: (HYPER AND CALM) If the dot on the bar is towards left,
>   the character is hyper. (They usually say "I'm itchin' for a fight!")
>   but of the dot is on the right, the character is calm. (They usually
>   say "Your sight irritates me.")
>
> BOTH BARS DO NOT EFFECT HOW SKILLED THE CHARACTER IS.

Judging from other articles and forum threads on the matter, these bars decide what your character says before and after the fight.

Comment: The reason I accepted this answer, is because I could verify myself that both bars *do* change what the character says.